# Как сделать динамические мета-теги?

Tags: php, динамические-массивы

Есть сайт в формате site.ru, есть алиас домена krd.site.ru
PHP-формулой задается динамическое изменение локального контента (город, телефоны, карты)
Как сделать также динамические мета-теги description, keywords и title?
Тоже, чтобы в них менялся город.
Динамический контент осуществляется PHP-кодом, прикрепляю.

```html
{source}<?php if (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'krd.site.ru') !== false){ echo "Краснодаре"; } else { echo "Санкт-Петербурге";}
?>{/source}
```

Comment: также как и с title только <meta name="description" content="Описание страницы сайта." />

Comment: $title='Краснодар';

echo '<meta name="description" content='.$title.' />';

Comment: @Bloom подскажите, пожалуйста, конкретно в моем случае. Я использую Joomla CMS, если указываю параметры в index.php шаблона, то параметры прикрепляются ко всему сайту, можно ли привязать PHP-код к определенной странице?